# How to query sum of corresponding element of an nested input list?

Tags: python, sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to output a list of lists of SUMS with an input of a list of lists of regular expressions. 
The code (Python with Oracle DB) looks something like this:

```
**my_query** = """SELECT SUM(col) FROM table t WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(t.col2, {reg_expr})"""
outer_list_of_regex = [[reg1,reg2,reg3],[reg4,reg5,reg6],[reg7,reg8,reg9],[reg10,reg11,reg12]]
list_of_sums = []
for inner_list_of_regex in outer_list_of_regex:
   temp_list = []
   for regex in inner_list_of_regex:
      inner_list.append(**my_query**.format(reg_expr = regex))
```

The input for the query is a list of lists of regular expressions.. the output is of the same format but is the sum of each of the elements returned in the same format and corresponding position as the input.
This structure works fine with short lists, but once it scales even to a reasonable length, it's too slow to put into production. Is there a way to reconfigure this without nested for-loops?

For example, perhaps one query with the nested list could output the sums for each of the corresponding regular expressions.

```
query = """select ([SUM(reg1),SUM(reg2),SUM(reg3)],[SUM(reg4)....]) FROM table t WHERE t.col2 == {outer_list_of_regex}"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a single query that returns your expected result by leveraging *conditional aggregation*:

```
select
    sum(case when regexp_like(col2, {reg1}) then col1 end) reg1,
    sum(case when regexp_like(col2, {reg2}) then col1 end) reg2,
    sum(case when regexp_like(col2, {reg3}) then col1 end) reg3
    ...
from mytable t
where 
    regexp_like(col2, {reg1})
    or regexp_like(col2, {reg2})
    or regexp_like(col2, {reg2})
    or ...
```

The query accepts a list of regexes as parameters (`{reg1}`, `{reg2}`, `{reg3}`, ...) and returns one column for each regex with the sum of `col1` for each record where `col2` matches the regex.